# Why is my object getting serialized into a string not text in my Rails ActiveRecord DB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am currently trying to store a user object accessed from the Soundcloud API into my local rails ActiveRecord database. The object acts like a hash.

**This is what the object/hash looks like:**

`#<SoundCloud::HashResponseWrapper avatar_url="https://i1.sndcdn.com/avatars-000296065573-ewlbh2-large.jpg"` `city="Brooklyn" country="United States" description="Raising The Bar Since 2007" discogs_name=nil first_name="Fool's" followers_count=7993682 followings_count=84 full_name="Fool's Gold" id=5636679 kind="user" last_modified="2018/03/09 19:40:55 +0000" last_name="Gold" myspace_name=nil online=false permalink="foolsgoldrecs"` `permalink_url="http://soundcloud.com/foolsgoldrecs" plan="Pro Plus" playlist_count=250 public_favorites_count=808 reposts_count=449 subscriptions=#<Hashie::Array [#<SoundCloud::HashResponseWrapper product=#<SoundCloud::HashResponseWrapper id="creator-pro-unlimited" name="Pro Unlimited">>]> track_count=1037 uri="https://api.soundcloud.com/users/5636679" username="Fool's Gold Records" website="http://smarturl.it/FoolsGoldSpotify" website_title="Spotify">`

**My ActiveRecord Schema.rb**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20180323143520) do

  create_table "soundcloud_users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "user_name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.text "user_hash"
  end

end
```

**What I have tried:**
Researching how to serialize objects in Ruby I found that I was supposed to make the field-to-be-serialized of type 'text'. I have made two different attempts at serializing then de-serializing the data, all of which have failed. Here is what I did:

1) Serialize as a Hash.

Code I tried:

```
class SoundcloudUser < ApplicationRecord
  serialize :user_hash, Hash
end
```

I then get this Error:

```
TypeError in SoundcloudQueriesController#create
allocator undefined for Proc
```

2) Serialize using YAML:
Code I tried:

```
class SoundcloudUser < ApplicationRecord
  YAML::dump(:user_hash)
end
```

This time I don't get an error. When I try to access the hash I wrote this code in my index def just to display it quickly:

```
 def index
    @user = SoundcloudUser.find(2)
    @user_hash = YAML::load(@user.user_hash)
  end
```

However, I for some reason cannot access the parameters the way I expect i.e. `@user_hash.followers_count`.

So I decided to go into `rails console` and see what was going on:

```
> @user = SoundcloudUser.find(6)
> @user_hash = @user.user_hash
> @user_hash.class
 => String
```

So for some reason, even though the field in active record is text, it is getting stored as a string? Or maybe the read back is converting it to a string? I really don't know what's going on, but am a bit lost. It's my first time serializing data, and the Soundcloud API has always returned weird objects that never work the way I expect. SUPER appreciate any help or advice!

**EDIT #2:**

Trying with JSON as per suggestion
When I changed my code as you prescribed, I still get the same issue:

**SoundCloudQueriesController.rb**

```
  def index

  end

  def create
    @user_url = params[:soundcloud_url]
    @soundcloud_user = SoundcloudUser.new
    @query = Query.new
    @user = @query.query_user(@user_url)
    @soundcloud_user.user_name = @user.username
    @soundcloud_user.user_hash = JSON.parse(@user.to_json).symbolize_keys
    @soundcloud_user.save
  end
```

**SoundcloudUser.rb (model)**

```
class SoundcloudUser < ApplicationRecord
end
```

**Output (querying the database in `rails console`):**

Typing in the following commands into rails console:
@user = SoundcloudUser.find(7)
@user_hash = @user.user_hash

This gives the following output of the hash (which still seems to be weirdly formatted with the "\" that weren't there before):

=> 
`"{:id=>8, :kind=>\"user\", :permalink=>\"alex\", :username=>\" \", :last_modified=>\"2018/03/15 18:15:56 +0000\",` `:uri=>\"https://api.soundcloud.com/users/8\", :permalink_url=>\"http://soundcloud.com/alex\",` `:avatar_url=>\"https://i1.sndcdn.com/avatars-000208970259-vngd3i-large.jpg\", :country=>\"Germany\", :first_name=>\"Alexander\", :last_name=>\"Ljung\", :full_name=>\"Alexander Ljung\", :description=>\"Hi, my name is Alex. I like Sound. Founder & Chairman, SoundCloud.\",` `:city=>\"Berlin/NYC\", :discogs_name=>nil, :myspace_name=>nil, :website=>nil, :website_title=>nil, :track_count=>268, :playlist_count=>34, :online=>false, :plan=>\"Pro Plus\", :public_favorites_count=>1601, :followers_count=>185322, :followings_count=>1697, :subscriptions=>[{\"product\"=>{\"id\"=>\"creator-pro-unlimited\", \"name\"=>\"Pro Unlimited\"}}], :reposts_count=>132}"`

When I try to access the hash as you prescribed:

```
> @user_hash[:followers_count]
```

I get the following message:

```
TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer
    from (irb):6:in `[]'
    from (irb):6
```

Weirdly enough, it gives the same error even for fields that are not integer values like :followers_count (:username for example).

I think you are right, this is not a hash. So now I am super lost at how to store this in my database haha. I tried just storing it with no serialization, but I get the same issue of it being seemingly converted to a string.

Comment: just leave `serialize :user_hash` in your model and treat the `:user_hash` field as a regular ruby hash. Rails will do all serialization/deserialization work for you.

Comment: Nice schill for getting soundcloud plays for your band! lol. J/K But If @nattfodd comment doesn't work, can you post your controller code?

Comment: Hey nattfodd, this doesn't work. This is the first thing I tried, but if you read my write-up, I get the error that I put there.

haha thanks laostenycoder, just trying to do some simple learning with the API (plays would get me banned from API lol). I will share the git link here in a second

Comment: @lacostenycoder here is the repo (I am just doing a simplification of my main app to get through these basics :) )
https://github.com/gaelant/simple_soundcloud_app

Comment: @gallant how are you populating the hash data in the database?

Comment: The data object you've shown in your question is nothing like a hash object.  We need to first figure out what you're doing to populate this data.  It's not correct.

Comment: Hey lacosten! in my services folder there is a simple model that pulls the data from soundcloud. The data that is pulled is shown at the start of my question.

How I put the data into the database is the simple line in my SoundcloudQueriesController:

(see the bottom of my post, I put the controller text there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see in your source code:

```
class Query
  def initialize
    @client = Soundcloud.new(:client_id => API_KEY)
  end

  def query_user(user_url)
    @user_url = user_url
    @user = @client.get('/resolve', :url => @user_url)
  end
end
```

At this point `@user` is a still a `SoundCloud::HashResponseWrapper` object.
If you wanna store the data as string text you'll need to first do:

```
@user.to_json
```

To save it with symbolized keys in the db:

```
data = JSON.parse(@user.to_json).symbolize_keys
sc_user = SoundcloudUser.new(user_hash: data)
```

But you still can't call `.key` on a hash. If you want to call the value of the key you'll need to do:

```
sc_user.user_hash[:username] #for example
```

There are ways to extend your model but that's out of scope for this question.

UPDATE:  Here's your updated controller:

```
class SoundcloudQueriesController < ApplicationController
  def new

  end

  def index
    @user = SoundcloudUser.find(3)
    @user_hash = @user.user_hash # but do you even need this?
  end

  def create
    sc_user_data = Query.new.get_user params[:username]
    @soundcloud_user = SoundcloudUser.create({
        user_name: sc_user_data[:username],
        user_hash: JSON.parse(sc_user_data.to_json).symbolize_keys
    })
  end

  def show

  end
end
```

You'll also need to modify your Query class to be able to build a user from the souncloud username.  It will look like this:

```
class Query
  BASE_RESOLVE_URL="http://soundcloud.com/"

  def initialize
    @client = Soundcloud.new :client_id => ENV['SC_CLIENT_ID']
  end

  def query_user(user_url)
    @user_url = user_url
    @user = @client.get('/resolve', :url => @user_url)
  end

  def get_user(username)
    @client.get('/resolve', url: BASE_RESOLVE_URL+username)
  end

end
```

I'm not exactly sure what you want to use the `query_user` method for, or if you can just remove it and use `get_user` instead.  In any case I forked your repo, got the controller create test passing.  Will send PR.

Comment: Hey lacost! Thanks again for all your help. I updated my answer above (see Edit #2). It still doesn't work with your changes :(

Comment: What "doesn't work"?  what error message do you get in what part of your app?  I tested the controller method and it works fine.  I also simplified the code. see updated code.

Comment: I did what I could to clean it up see https://github.com/gaelant/simple_soundcloud_app/pull/1

Comment: Hey Lacost! WOW man!! This is so awesome, thank you for this. I looked over your pull and really learned a lot from the code. I have a few questions for you but my internet keeps dieing, and I am having a bunch of issues with my local network installing gems (DNS issues). Quick note though: I pulled your commits to my master and tried to run rails server, however the index `<% @users.each do |u| %>` code stops it from running giving the following error: `NoMethodError in` `SoundcloudQueries#index ` with detail: `/index.html.erb where line #5 raised: undefined method []' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: PS I commented out this code to maybe re-populate the database with an entry. Upon doing that and un-commenting out the index.html.erb code, it still gave the same error. I have never used the `pry` gem so my initial attempts to rails console in and see what the database was doing didn't work. Had to run though (posting this from phone) but just wanted to post an update for you. Thank you so much for all your help Lacost, I checked out your soundcloud too, really cool music ;)

Comment: glad I was able to help. I'll message you on github and see what we can figure out.

Comment: Sounds great. I will mark as answered as you really helped and put so much effort in.